# How can I do equivalent of memcpy from a raw array to a std::vector?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, memcpy

I have a class that has (amongst many other things) a pointer to unsigned char that gets deleted and reallocated to store some data from another array. This done with a function

```
 class MyClass {
  private:
      unsigned char* m_Buffer;
      int m_BufferSize;
  public:
      bool SetBuffer(int iSize, const unsigned char* pArray); 
 };

 bool MyClass::SetBuffer(int iSize, const unsigned char* pArray) {
     bool bOK = false;
     if (pArray != NULL  && iSize > 0) {
         delete [] m_Buffer;
         m_Buffer = new unsigned char[iSize];
         memcpy(m_Buffer,pArray,iSize);
         m_BufferSize = iSize;
         bOK = true;
      }
      return bOK;
  }
```

I dont like this code at all, and I would really like to replace the pointer with a `std::vector<unsigned char>`. My question is, how would I perform the memcpy aspect? If I were passing a vector in as argument to my function, I could copy it using iterators, but I have no control over parameter argument type so I am stuck with `unsigned char*` . Is there a way of using iterators, or sizing the vector to the right size and then accessing its internal array so that I can still copy the data with `memcpy` ? Or even better something using iterators?? I know I could use a loop and `push_back` but that seems painfully inefficient to me. Any suggestions will be gratefully received.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually, iterators are modelled from pointers and therefore pointers within an array are considered to implement the `RandomAccessIterator` concept.

Therefore:

```
m_buffer.assign(pArray, pArray + Size);
```

Comment: Will this automatically resize the vector or would I have to call clear and set the size of it to the size of the array?

Comment: @mathematician1975 see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign). You don't have to call clear, resize or anything.

Comment: Note that this will *not* reduce the capacity.  If you want the vector to use exactly the amount of memory required, and no more, you have to do something like `std::vector<unsigned char>( pArray, pArray + Size ).swap( m_buffer );`.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I wonder about the *no more*. As far as I know an implementation is free to allocate whatever capacity it deems suitable, so even though you only set `Size` elements it could perfectly jump to the nearest power of 2 (typical...). Of course, you are right about `assign` not reducing the capacity.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Formally, I think you're right.  All the standard guarantees is that `capacity() >= size()` when you newly construct an `std::vector`.  In practice, for all of the implementations I've seen, `capacity() == size()` _if_ the size can be calculated in constant time before starting initialization of the elements (i.e. constructors where the size is given, or which use random access iterators, as is the case here).

Answer (score 0):

I really advise you to avoid raw pointers this way. I think that is a better idea to manage std::vectors instead of the raw pointers.

```
class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<unsigned char> m_Buffer;
    // No size member is needed, it is stored in m_Buffer
public:
    // No size parameter is needed, it is stored in Array
    void SetBuffer(const std::vector<unsigned char> &Array);
};

void MyClass::SetBuffer(const std::vector<unsigned char> &Array) {
    std::copy(Array.begin(), Array.end(), m_Buffer.begin());
}
```

Assuming that  your dessing forces to have a raw managed for `MyClass` you will take care of this pointer on copy constructors and `operator =` (or get rid of it instead):

```
MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass &Class) {
    m_BufferSize = Class.m_BufferSize;
    m_Buffer = new new unsigned char[m_BufferSize];
    memcpy(m_Buffer, Class.m_Buffer, m_BufferSize); 
}

MyClass::operator =(const MyClass &Class) {
    if (m_Buffer) delete [] m_Buffer;
    m_BufferSize = Class.m_BufferSize;
    m_Buffer = new new unsigned char[m_BufferSize];
    memcpy(m_Buffer, Class.m_Buffer, m_BufferSize); 
}
```

If you don't take care of the `MyClass` managed pointers in the copy constructor and `operator =` you will end with two instances of `MyClass` managing the same memory.

Comment: The question is explicitly about replacing the current pointer to array + size by a `vector`.

Comment: Yes, I'd realized after posting. But in the end, the advising is the same, I think that is better use `std::vector` instead raw pointers.